# Updating Shipping details for digital orders using PayPal API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using paypal Standard checkout using Rest API for digital orders. As soon as the client pay, the order is marked as COMPLETED. Now, I have to update the shipping details by going to txn page => Add Tracking info => Select order status => Order processed (Tracking no. not required) => submit.

[image]

I tried to do this using API by first getting the orderID from [https://api.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/{payment](https://api.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/%7Bpayment) ID} and then getting the order details from [https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{order_id};](https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/%7Border_id%7D;)

But couldn't understand how do I update this status and which endpoint will work? Updating a number of orders manually is very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

See the [add package tracking](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/) documentation.

Here is an example API request that adds tracking to an order. The items sent are the same as the ones in the original create/capture order (sku values must match)

POST to https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T/track

```
{ 
"capture_id": "8MC585209K746392H", 
"tracking_number": "443844607820", 
"carrier": "FEDEX", 
"notify_payer": true, 
"items": [{
  "sku": "sku01",
  "quantity": "1",
  "name": "T-Shirt",
  "description": "Green T-Shirt",
  "image_url": "https://example.com/static/images/items/1/tshirt_green.jpg",
  "url": "https://example.com/url-to-the-item-being-purchased-1",
  "upc": {
    "type": "UPC-A",
    "code": "123456789012"
  }
}, {
  "sku": "sku02",
  "quantity": "2",
  "name": "Shoes",
  "description": "Running, Size 10.5",
  "image_url": "https://example.com/static/images/items/1/shoes_running.jpg",
  "url": "https://example.com/url-to-the-item-being-purchased-2",
  "upc": {
    "type": "UPC-A",
    "code": "987654321012"
  }
}]
}
```

---

Since your question is about digital orders (no physical items), tracking is less useful. The best solution in your case may be to create/capture the order with no shipping information. The [parameter to set](https://POST%20https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T/track) is payment_source.paypal.experience_context.shipping_preference = "NO_SHIPPING"

Additionally, when including an `items` array, each item's category can be [set to DIGITAL_GOODS](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create!path=purchase_units/items/category&t=request)